# Port is not opening/assigning on the nuxt+Vue app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js

Not sure what I'm missing, here is my code. please consider **web** container
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7.8.0-alpine

<.... more lines here>

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

RUN cd /usr/src/app/
# start command
RUN npm run dev

EXPOSE 3000


#CMD [ "npm", "run dev" ]
```

docker-compose file:

```
web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./web/src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:3000
    depends_on:
      - genaretors-csv-services
```

[image]

Comment: where does WEB_PORT coming from? does it work when you hadcode 3000:3000 ?

Comment: What's the `CMD` the image runs?  Can you include the complete Dockerfile, and the actual error messages you're getting?  What's the image you've attached to the question?

Comment: @pszaba WEB_PORT is coming from .env file and Not even working if I replace variable with the value